# Magento 2 - extention attribute not available

Tags: magento2

1. I've implemented `extention attribute` for Customer Shipping Address. This is "Office" selection on the Checkout page, where customer can choose from.
2. Once Checkout Page first loads and customer picks an Office, the `extention attribute` is undefined.
3. If you then go further to the Payment step, then go back to the shipping step and pick the Office up again, the `extention attribute` is propely filled with the selected Office value. The `extention attribute` is 'visible' now.

Please advice me on this. Many thanks!